# Default a grid value from a prior line in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How would you write code to set a default value on a grid with the value of the field from the line above it?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be this.  Let us suppose you want to default the quantity on the Bills and Adjustments screen, with the quantity from the prior line.  Consider using the pattern below.

```
public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    protected void APTran_Qty_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (APTran)e.Row;
        if (row == null) return;

        // get prior qty and default it here, unless it is already set.
        if (row.Qty == null)
        {
            decimal? priorQty = GetPriorQtyInGrid(row);
            if (priorQty != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = priorQty;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    public decimal? GetPriorQtyInGrid(APTran currentRow)
    {
        APTran lastline = null;
        foreach (APTran line in Base.Transactions.Select())
        {
            if (currentRow == line)
            {
                break;
            }
            lastline = line;
        }

        if (lastline != null)
            return lastline.Qty;
        else
            return null;

    }
    #endregion
}
```

[image]